# Is there a data source indicating how long most major surgeries take, and what are the associated risks/outcomes?

Tags: surgery, health-informatics

I'm looking to play around with statistics around major surgery types; is there a publicly available data source I can work with which lists information such as:

- types of major surgeries, together with amount of time per procedure (average, standard deviation, broken down by complication, etc...)
- risk information to any level of detail
- any sort of other aggregate information

Any data set would be interesting (ie, for any geographical region or legal jurisdiction - i know some of this info might be harder to collect in say the US than elsewhere)

Comment: The question could be more suitable for: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suitable for: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/